# Basic DNN with highly imbalanced dataset -- network predicts same labels

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I will try to explain my issue at a high level, and I hope I'd be able to get some better understanding of the ML behind it all.

I am working with aggregated features extracted from audio files, so each feature vector is of size (1xN). The output would be a single sentiment label, Positive, Neutral, or Negative. I mapped these to 2, 1, 0 respectively (the labels are discrete by design, but maybe I could make it continuous?)

The dataset I am using is 90% neutral, 6% negative, and 4% positive, and I split these into train/dev/test. I wrote up a basic DNN in PyTorch, and have been training using CrossEntropyLoss and SGD (with nesterov momentum). The issue I am running into is that the network, after seeing only ~10% of the data, starts to predict only netural labels. The class weights converge to something like

```
tensor([[-0.9255],
        [ 1.9352],
        [-1.1473]])
```

no matter what 1xN feature vectors you feed in. I would appreciate guidance on how to address this issue.

For reference, the architecture is

```
DNNModel(
  (in_layer): Linear(in_features=89, out_features=1024, bias=True)
  (fcs): Sequential(
    (0): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=512, bias=True)
    (1): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=256, bias=True)
    (2): Linear(in_features=256, out_features=128, bias=True)
  )
  (out_layer): Sequential(
    (0): SequenceWise (
    Linear(in_features=128, out_features=3, bias=True))
  )
)

def forward(self, x):
    x =  F.relu(self.in_layer(x))
    for fc in self.fcs:
        x = F.relu(fc(x))
    x = self.out_layer(x)
    return x
```

Not sure if NN actually makes sense -- could it be the relus between each hidden layer or the bias? Or something else. Thanks!

EDIT: Moved to Data Science Stack Exchange, since this is more relevant there. [link](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/35807/basic-dnn-with-highly-imbalanced-dataset-network-predicts-same-labels)

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51433774/781723, https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/35807/8560.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.  Making another post is not moving it; it is making a second copy.

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to get through this problem.You could try re-sampling your dataset.

This can be done in two ways :

1. You could either try under-sampling i.e, delete instances of the over represented class ,or
2. You could try over-sampling i.e, add more instances of the under represented class.

This is probably the simplest way but if you are willing to try this you could try penalised models.

In penalised models we impose an additional cost on the model for making classification mistakes on the minority class during training.This additional cost cost or penalties can make the model pay more attention to the minority class.There are penalised versions of algorithms such as penalised-svm and others.

For more information on the penalised-svm algorithm you could follow this link:
 **[https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122095/does-support-vector-machine-handle-imbalanced-dataset][1]**

Comment: Yes, I was thinking that SVMs and simpler models would be easier to understand, and thus probably easier to fix up. Thanks for the links! I do want to get a basic DNN working if possible though.